# How to globally handle custom thrown exceptions in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

Inside **main.dart** I am using the 2 callbacks for handling exceptions caught by flutter and not caught by flutter as follows:

```
void main() async {

  MyErrorsHandler.initialize();
  FlutterError.onError = (details) async {
    FlutterError.presentError(details);
    MyErrorsHandler.onErrorDetails(details);
  };

  PlatformDispatcher.instance.onError = (error, stack){
    MyErrorsHandler.onError(error, stack);
    return true;
  };

  runApp(const ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));
}
```

But when I throw exceptions myself like when making an HTTP request:

```
 static Future<BasketViewDto> getAsync(String basketId) async {

    final url = Uri.parse('${ApiConfigurations.BaseUrl}/Baskets/$basketId');

    final response = await http.get(url);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final result = json.decode(response.body)['result'];

      final BasketViewDto basket = BasketViewDto.fromJson(result);

      return basket;
    } else {
      throw Exception("Failed to get Basket");
    }
  }
```

OnError does not catch that exception. So how can I define a global place where I can handle(log) all exceptions that I throw in any place inside my code?

Comment: how do you call `getAsync`?

Comment: Inside state class I define late Future<BasketViewDto> basket; and inside initState() i call basket = BasketApi.getAsync(basketId); then I use Futurebuilder to get the result and build the page.

Comment: Do you get any errors in your console?

Comment: your handler would catch the exception if you `await`ed that method result - I mean: `final foo = await getAsync();`

Comment: No, I don't want to await for the result because I need Basket to be late Future of that BasketViewDto and not BasketViewDto where it's good for performance so I don't block other aspect of widget tree to be rendered

Answer (score 1):

According to the [latest documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?platform=flutter), add this to your setup:
`Isolate.current.addErrorListener(RawReceivePort((pair) async {

```
  // To catch errors that happen outside of the Flutter context, an error listener on the main Isolate is required
  final List<dynamic> errorAndStacktrace = pair;
  await FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordError(
    errorAndStacktrace.first,
    errorAndStacktrace.last,
    fatal: true,
  );
}).sendPort);`
```